# Need to uncheck other checkboxes when one of them is checked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using aura:iteration for the checkboxes as below--

```
                    <table class="slds-table slds-no-row-hover slds- 
                     table_striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                                <th>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Quote Id</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">View</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <aura:iteration indexVar="index" items="{!v.listQuotes}" var="quote">
                                <tr id="{!quote.Id}">
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:input aura:id="chkbox" id="{!quote.Id}" type="checkbox" onchange="{!c.checkboxSelect}"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="{!index}" class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">{!quote.Name}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:button name="{!quote.Id}" variant="base" label="View" title="View" onclick="{!c.viewQuote}" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Now when I check the checkbox, I need to uncheck other checkboxes, so that at any given time I have just one Id with me.

I am not able to find a way to do that--
Here is what I tried--

```
checkboxSelect : function(component, event, helper) {
    var quoteRecId = event.getSource().get("v.id");
    var checkValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");

    console.log('Inside checkbox Select-->'+quoteRecId); 
    console.log('Inside checkbox Select checkValue-->'+checkValue); 
    var quotes = component.get("v.listQuotes");
    var resetChecks= [];
    for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++){ 
       if (quotes[i].Id !== quoteRecId) {
            component.find(quotes[i].Id).set("v.value", false);
       }
    }

}
```

Console Logs--

```
Inside checkbox Select-->a0222000001ssxGAAQ
EmployerViewQuotes.js:28 Inside checkbox Select checkValue-->
```

Comment: Checkboxes don't use `v.value`. Use `v.checked` instead.

Comment: you should be able to figure this out by reading both the question/answer in the linked post.